# Calculation data from one array to another

Tags: arrays, matlab, kernel

I have two array, the first one is data_array(50,210), the second one is dest_array(210,210). The goal, using data from data_array to calculate the values of dest_array at specific indicies, without using for-loop.

I do it in such way:

```
function [ out ] = grid_point( row,col,cg_row,cg_col,data,kernel )
ker_len2 = floor(length(kernel)/2);
op1_vals = data((row - ker_len2:row + ker_len2),(col - ker_len2:col + ker_len2));
out(cg_row,cg_col) = sum(sum(op1_vals.*kernel)); %incorre
end

function [ out ] = sm(dg_X, dg_Y)
%dg_X, dg_Y - arrays of size 210x210, the values - coordinates of data in data_array,
%index of each element - position this data at 210x210 grid

data_array = randi(100,50,210); %data array

kernel = kernel_sinc2d(17,'hamming'); %sinc kernel for calculations
ker_len2 = floor(length(kernel)/2);

%adding the padding for array, to avoid 
%the errors related to boundaries of data_array
data_array = vertcat(data_array(linspace(ker_len2+1,2,ker_len2),:),...
                     data_array,...
                     data_array(linspace(size(data_array,1)-1,size(data_array,1) - ker_len2,ker_len2),:));

data_array = horzcat(data_array(:,linspace(ker_len2+1,2,ker_len2)),...
                     data_array,...
                     data_array(:,linspace(size(data_array,2)-1,(size(data_array,2) - ker_len2,ker_len2)));

%cg_X, cg_Y - arrays of indicies for X and Y directions
[cg_X,cg_Y] = meshgrid(linspace(1,210,210),linspace(1,210,210));

%for each point at grid(210x210) formed by cg_X and cg_Y, 
%we should calculate the value, using the data from data_array(210,210).

%after padding, data_array will have size (50 + ker_len2*2, 210 + ker_len2*2)

dest_array = arrayfun(@(y,x,cy,cx) grid_point(y, x, cy, cx, data_array, kernel),...
                      dg_Y, dg_X, cg_Y, cg_X);
end
```

But, it seems that arrayfun cannot resolve my problem, because I use arrays with different sizes. Have somebody the ideas of this?

Comment: Your example is very long, please reduce it to the minimum example that still shows your problem. Also describe what exactly the problem is. For example, do you get any errors? Preferably even add a small scale example with inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure, but judging from the title, this may be what you want:

```
%Your data
data_array_small = rand(50,210)
data_array_large = zeros(210,210)
%Indicating the points of interest
idx = randperm(size(data_array_large,1));
idx = idx(1:size(data_array_small,1))

%Now actually use the information:
data_array_large(idx,:)  = data_array_small
```